# Create a Video from Images with Blank Audio

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I want to create a video from some images to use in the DashWare program.
One of the requirements is that the video must have an audio track.

If I create a sequence of JPG and join them with an audio, the result is the desired one.

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 29.97 -i Pictures_% 5d.jpg -i audio.mp3 -vf scale = "2560: 1440" output.mp4
```

I would like to do better and I would like that when the video is created directly a blank audio track is created.
I have managed to do it with this sequence but I have the problem that an endless video is generated. If you put a -t clause then the video lasts as long as you indicate, but I don't want to do so since it is to make different videos and they will have a different duration.

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i anullsrc -framerate 29.97 -i Pictures_% 5d.jpg -vf scale = "2560: 1440" Output.mp4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-shortest`:

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i anullsrc -framerate 29.97 -i Pictures_% 5d.jpg -vf "scale=2560:1440" -shortest Output.mp4
```

Consider using 30000/1001 instead of 29.97 if you want actual NTSC frame rate.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you so much.. For set 30000/1001, the order is - r 30, or -framerate 30000/1001?

Comment: @RBenet It is `-framerate 30000/1001` (or the [alias](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Video-rate) `-framerate ntsc`) when used as an input option for the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) like in the answer. `-r` is used if you want to also change the output frame rate. Why use both? For example if you want to input frames at a really low frame rate, but your player only accepts normal rates you can add `-r` output option to duplicate frames to reach the desired output rate. Output will look the same.

Comment: ok , Thank's again. I learn two things today,

Comment: if 30.000/1.001=29,97002997002997 Is not the same to put 29.97?

Comment: @RBenet No, they are technically not the same. 29.97 is just shorthand. Long videos will end up with a different number of frames.